# Falha no acesso do SPServices em uma lista do SharePoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

Criei um SPServices que consulta uma lista no SharePoint 2010 e retorna o valor de um único campo. Porém, esta consulta esta retornando o seguinte erro:

```
soap:ServerException of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.NÃ£o existe nenhuma Web chamada "/blog/Lists/Postagens/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx".
```

Meu código é o seguinte:

```
var queryText = "<Query>"+
                    "<Where>"+
                        "<Eq>"+
                            "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>"+
                                "<Value Type='Number'>" + IDPost + "</Value>"+
                        "</Eq>"+
                    "</Where>"+
                "</Query>";

 $().SPServices({
    operation: 'GetListItems',
    async: false,
    listName: 'Postagens',
    webURL: 'http://site/subsite/Lists/Postagens/',
    CAMLViewFields: '<ViewFields>'+
                        '<FieldRef Name="Curtir" />'+
                    '</ViewFields>',
    CAMLQuery : queryText,      
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode('z:row').each(function() {
            CurtirTot = $(this).attr('ows_Curtir');
        });
    }
});
```

Procurei no google, mas o resultado mais próximo que cheguei foi "Falha na conectividade"
Alguém sabe me dizer se eu preciso configurar algo mais no SharePoint para funcionar corretamente o SPServices ou existe algum erro no código ?

Answer (score 1):

A opção `webURL` deve indicar o caminho de um site. No seu código que ele indica o caminho de uma lista.

Modifique o valor da opção para conter o caminho apenas até o site, isto é, supondo que o site se chame *"subsite"* e esteja no caminho do domínio *"site"*, ficaria assim:

```
...
    webURL: `'http://site/subsite/'`,
...
```

Comment: Tentei tirar o parâmetro "WebURL" e funcionou. Obrigada

Comment: Sobre esse parâmetro, ele deve ser utilizado somente quando você for fazer requisições de um site a outro. Se você está no próprio site *blog*, então ele é realmente dispensável.